# Boot from USB OTG by corrupting boot image

Tags: boot

I'm trying to write a script that boots my device into FEL mode (device boots from USB OTG port). Normally, this is only possible by pushing a physical "flash" button on the PCBA during boot up. Here is the boot flow for the device:

```
boot-> check fel key pressed (yes)--> FEL mode (boot from USB OTG)
                      \  
                  (no) \
                        \-------> 1) try to boot from SMHC0 (SD card)
                                  2) try to boot from SMHC2 (eMMC)
                                  3) try to boot from SPI0 (SPI NOR Flash)
                                  4) FEL mode (boot from USB OTG)
```

So if the Boot ROM doesn't find any valid boot image, it will automatically enter FEL mode (see more about this here: https://linux-sunxi.org/FEL#Triggering_FEL_mode). My idea is to write a script to intentionally corrupt the bootloader or the boot image so that the Boot ROM will fail and fall through to FEL mode. Then, after a reboot, I should enter FEL mode.

I get that this is probably undesirable in many ways. But is this possible? How would I go about corrupting the bootloader and/or boot image so that the Boot ROM fails?

Note: I don't have access to a serial console and there is no way to use an SD card image.